# Export and save document

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `SendKeys` but sometimes in the middle of execution it will process some steps faster than others, or it will not copy and make a blank document, or lastly it will be stuck on a blank notepad opening up.

Looking for a more reliable export and save function.

I tried adding DoEvents to verify it does each step.

```vb
Sub export_one_column()

    Dim fdObj As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Call_Log") Then
    Else
        fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Call_Log")
        MsgBox "Call Log Folder has been created in your C\ Folder.", vbInformation, "Creating Folder"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Sheets("PrintTXT").Select
    Columns(3).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Shell "notepad.exe", 3
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "^v"
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "^s"
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "C:\Call_Log" & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"            '<<==== Change
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "%fx"
    DoEvents
    SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
    
    Sheets("ENTRY FORM").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub export_one_column()

Dim fdObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fdObj.FolderExists("C:\Call_Log") Then
Else
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\Call_Log")
    MsgBox "Call Log Folder has been created in your C\ Folder.", vbInformation, "Creating Folder"
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim LastRow As Long, tmpRange As Range, strFilename as String

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PrintTXT")
        LastRow = .Columns("C").Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set tmpRange = .Range("C1").Resize(LastRow)
    End With

    strFilename = "C:\Call_Log" & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"

    With Workbooks.Add
        .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(LastRow).Value = tmpRange.Value
        .SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlText
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    Set tmpRange = Nothing
End Sub
```